# Application can't connect to Oracle Database through VPN

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

We have an application that works correctly when open through a PC that is connected to internal network, but, when i'm outside the company and connected throught VPN, the application returns error saying that is not possible to connect to the database. Everying is ok with the settings of VPN, when i ping to the database server thought VPN it responds, but, when i try to open the application, it can't connect to the database (only when through VPN)

Is there any chance to be some configuration on oracle database? Can you please help me? I can garantee that everying is fine about the VPN configuration/networks, but can't tell about oracle if everything is ok.

Thank you so much!

[Print of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoEcH.jpg)

Comment: Is there any restriction on the source IP for database connections, either in a db server system firewall or in the db server's sqlnet.ora file with INVITED_NODES? Do you use Oracle Connection Manager to restrict connections? Are you sure that the VPN is allowing connections on port 1521 (or whatever port Oracle is listening on)? Can you tnsping (not ping) from the VPN client to the database server?

Comment: It would certainly help if you updated your question to actually _show_ the actual error message, not just your description of it.

Comment: This is not a programming question and is off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @pmdba thank you, ill check your suggests.

Comment: @EdStevens Sorry for that! I just updated the post with a link to the print of the error. I Would be grateful if you can help. thanks!

Comment: ora-12170 - tns timeout.  Almost certainly a firewall issue.